# Dealing with NAs and blanks in MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have data on 100 individuals. The data is imported as integer values from a csv file into my MYSQL database. I have a php screen in which I can search for the max or min for each column of data.

In cases where there are blanks or `NA`s in the data, MYSQL is currently recognizing this as `0`s.  Problem is I want it to be recognized as blank or `NA` in the output.  It cannot be `NULL` either because the max and min does not recognize null values.

Comment: what field type does mysql thing "NA" is "0"? i really dont think this is possible

Comment: i see what your saying i was interpreting it differently, yup you will end up with 0 if you try put any string in to an int. NULL is the only option 'blank' is not possible for an int